# Is the Java's stack allocated size physical or logical?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, profiling, stack

I was wondering whether the stack allocated size we consider Java to have (for instance, 512k) is a logical size (meaning that in reality we are using more than than 512k, including all the    Hotspot overhead, for example), or is a physical limit (meaning that summing all the Java allocated things in the stack wouldn't ammount to anything like the 512k)?

It's hard to figure this out by testing, I'd say, as was seen in my other post: [Inferring a method's stack memory use in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432259/inferring-a-methods-stack-memory-use-in-java)

I'd like some sort of sources, if possible!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the distinction between physical and logical is a bit blurred in this case. Since HotSpot will JIT your code to native code at will, and the result may depend on a number of optimizations, one could argue that both views are in a way correct.

Or, one could say that the stack is physical, but what goes onto the stack is variable and not always simple to derive from the Java code being executed. For example, function calls may be inlined or not, so a call to your function from one place may need extra space on the stack and a call to the same function from another place or at another time may not need it or need less (or more). This is called deep inlining in [this document](http://java.sun.com/products/hotspot/whitepaper.html). If you push references onto the stack, their size may also vary (there are tricks which make it possible to sometimes squeeze references into 32 bits even in a 64-bit JVM). Since the JIT compiler works asynchronously and makes some decisions based on profiling data from code execution, the same code may have varying performance and probably also stack usage during different runs.

**EDIT:**
Garbage Collector, JIT compiler etc. run in separate threads, so they use their own call stacks, if that's what you mean by "HotSpot overhead".

Comment: I'll try to make myself a bit clearer. I've been dabbing JDK and HotSpot's code, and I've come to the conclusion that for instance, when making a method call, there's this big struct(JavaCallWrapper is how it's called) that's created filled with all this various information, like parameters, return data, thread info, etc. Of course, just the fact that this struct exists adds to the more obvious data one would assume to exist (like the parameters themselves, return data, the this parameter, etc). Would you "count" this JavaCallWrapper for the JVM's defined stack size?

Answer (score 2):

The stack size uses virtual memory until actually used.  This means your stack size could be 1 MB for every thread however the resident size might be only 32 KB.

This is because the OS allocates pages (typically 4 KB) to your program as you actually use them.

e.g. it allocates your maximum heap size on start up, but your program doesn't use that much main memory until every page is used.

You may have difficulty finding this information for the JVM specifically because this is functionality provided by the OS and all programs work this way. i.e. its not something special the JVM does.